# Saas Architecture

Tags: architecture, saas

I am basically a PHP programmer, now I want to move to Saas based application development and archicture. Can any one give me a technical approach that should be followed for the following Saas based Architecture or how can I convert the following to Saas,

1. Legacy to SaaS
2. Mobile to SaaS
3. Existing Application to SaaS
4. SaaS from  Scratch

Thank you for any help

Comment: Can you please elaborate on what you're trying to accomplish? Why SaaS? Can you define SaaS for your scenarios? What problems are you running into?

Answer (score 1):

First off, let's define what SaaS actually means:

> SaaS, Software As A Service: abbr., defines a software package whereby the customer pays a lump-sum monthly or yearly fee for
>   installation, operation, maintenance and support of the package,
>   typically on a 365x24x7 schedule, accessible from anywhere with internet access. Data safety and backup, privacy, scalability  are guaranteed
>   by the provider, without the customer having to worry about these
>   concerns. The main benefit to customers are: No need for capital expenses, continued support & maintenance included, faster time to market [by miraculixx].

Wikipedia has a slightly more [expansive definition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_as_a_service).

Considering this, any SaaS needs the following capabilities to make it viable to operate under this business model:

- support multi-tenancy
- automated installation and operation - you don't want to setup/operate every customer manually
- scalability - the system's overall cost should grow at most as fast as your income, ideally cost growth is sublinear
- proven security
- possibly an API + marketplace, enabling third parties to extend the software
- possibly i18n / l10n support to support international markets

> Can any one give me a technical approach that should be followed for the following Saas based Architecture

1. Check your software for the above capabilities
2. Extend and refactor as required
3. Launch a first, simple package to verify market demand is there
4. Extend and grow (or wrap up and do something else)

Answer (score 0):

If you are planning to use Python, you can use Django to build SaaS application.

This video [Build SaaS application in Python django](https://youtu.be/jg4qs9Qs6Fs) will explain about getting started with Sass.